# Volume of body bounded with surfaces

Tags: volume, plane-curves

I need to find volume bounded with $x=2y-y^2-z^2$ and $2y-x-1=0$. So first one is paraboloid that is located on x-axis and its "maximum" is in $(0,2,0)$ and the second is plane paralele to z-axis.
I just want to check do we get the volume when substract volume of $2y-x-1=0$ from paraboloid.(Also using polar coordinates it is easy to get $0\le r\le 1, 0\le \phi \le 2\pi$). I'm just not sure whether I sketched this correctly, precisely is given plane above paraboloid?

Comment: The vertex for the paraboloid is incorrect. Did you complete the square for the $y$?

Comment: Yes, and I've got $x=-(y-1)^2-z^2+1$.

Comment: Perfect, then you have the correct formula and the vertex is really $(1,1,0)$

Comment: Misscalculated that i guess. And for the volume is it correct to substract volume of plane from volume of paraboloid?

Comment: The volumes of both are infinite since they are open and unbounded, so that doesn't make sense directly. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean to find their intersection and I get $y^2+z^2=1$ and then convert to polar coordinates. Then get the volume as $\iint x_1(y,z)-x_2(y,z)$ where $x_1$ is plane and $x_2$ paraboloid.

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: @Trevor Yes the intersection points are on $y^2 + z^2 = 1$ but the intersection between the plane and the paraboloid is only between $-3 \leq x \leq 1$ or you can say $-1 \leq y \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the integral in different orders. A few of the examples are given below. But for some clarity on the volume bound between the plane and the paraboloid, they intersect only between $-3 \leq x \leq 1$. The two extreme points of intersection are $(1, 1, 0)$ and $(-3, -1, 0)$. In between, as you rightly pointed out, the intersection points are on $y^2 + z^2 = 1$

Integral setup -

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \int_{2y-1}^{2y-y^2-z^2} dx \, dz \, dy$

or

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \int_{2y-1}^{2y-y^2-z^2} dx \, dy \, dz$

In cylindrical coordinates -

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{2r\sin \theta - 1}^{2r \sin \theta - r^2} r \, dx \, dr \, d\theta$

Comment: Okey. I get evrything. Just what is mistake in doing with polar coordinates? Just saw you edited. That is the same way i done.

Comment: There is no mistake, I just updated with cylindrical coordinates. I assume that is what you meant?

Comment: Yep, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The intersection between $x = 2 y - 1$ and $x=-y^2+2 y-z^2$ is the circle

$y^2+z^2=1$, which means that the limits for $z$ and $y$ are
$$-\sqrt{1-y^2}\le z\le \sqrt{1-y^2};\;-1\le y\le 1$$
Thus the volume is
$$V=\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int _{2 y-1}^{-y^2+2 y-z^2}dxdzdy=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Hope this helps

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes viewing the volume helps:

[image]